# Intercept Data being sent to XBee Module via UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, xbee, wireless

An XBee Pro S1 module sits on a DIP socket on-board a Personal Weather Station (PWS) to transmit data. 
Instead of letting the station transmit data wirelessly via the XBee, I would like to read that data off the socket pins on which it sits, via an Arduino UNO.

Is this possible? If so, what should I look into?
I am new to wireless communication with a µC, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If i am getting you right, try connecting the tx pin of Xbee with the rx of UNO and then read the data coming in to the serial UART.

Comment: @AnumSheraz: thanks for that. I tried but Arduino did not pick up any data off pins 2 & 3 of the XBee socket (Tx & Rx pins). I'm guessing the settings (baud rate, parity, etc.) need to be known first before any meaningful data can be captured.